# Where can I find the "full path to java binary" on linux server?

Tags: java, linux, server

I apologize if this doesn't belong here, I am relatively new to this stuff.

I am have a module for drupal that needs to have java installed on the server. I followed the instructions and installed java. I am now trying to locate the java binary but none of the paths I have tried work. Is there something I am missing here? I can't seem to find any information online.

[The path I am having an issue with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPz4f.png)

Comment: Try the command `locate java`. Look for the one that looks like Java.

Comment: You want the `bin` (binary) directory that's under that path. The `java` executable will be in there. It's what you'll find with @ElliottFrisch's `locate java` command.

Comment: `which java` should do

Comment: Try `find / -name java`

Comment: In windows type `where java` in linux type `which java`

Comment: It's OS specific, and there are commands on each OS to run to extract this info,  Also the PATH be incorrectly set, need more info

Answer (score -1):

The comments have contained several suggestions.  However, the location of the Java binaries is OS specific (as well as Java manufacturer specific).  Please provide information regarding your OS and JDK.  JDK will likely be either HotSpot or OpenJDK).

That said, there are certain conventional locations.  My CentOS OpenJDK installation is located in [/usr/bin/java](http:///usr/bin/java).  This is identifiable using "which java" command.  Do not use the "locate" command - this will flood you with a lot of superfluous information.

It is also common to use the /opt folder to store non-OS binaries: /opt/java/jreXXX.

Several others have cited other commands.  These are not all the same:
    which java: provides the location of the java command executable
    whereis java: provides the location of the binary, source and man pages
    locate java: same as find, locates all files with java in their name